# При скачивании большого excel документа не все записи помещаются

Tags: php, excel

На сайте есть экспорт заказов. Заметил что при большом объеме данных (более 152 000 записей) excel-документ начинает обрезать последние записи. То-есть они не попадают в файл. С чем это может быть связано?

Привожу пример кода:

```
class Csv {

public function download_send_headers($filename) {
    // disable caching
    $now = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s");
    header("Expires: Tue, 03 Jul 2001 06:00:00 GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate");
    header("Last-Modified: {$now} GMT");

    // force download
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");
    header("Content-type: text/csv");

    // disposition / encoding on response body
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename={$filename}");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
}

public function array2csv(array &$array, $titles = null) {
    ob_start();
    $df = fopen("php://output", 'w');
    fprintf($df, chr(0xEF).chr(0xBB).chr(0xBF));
    if(!is_null($titles)) fputcsv($df, $titles, ";");
    foreach ($array as $row) {
        fputcsv($df, $row, ";");
    }
    fclose($df);
    return ob_get_clean();
}
}
```

Система проходим по выборке записей из БД (без буфера) и передает массив из 10 записей в класс выше, после чего выводит результат:

```
...
$this->csv->download_send_headers("data_export_" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
while(...){
    echo $this->csv->array2csv($rows);
}
die();
```

Это ограничения самого Excel-файла? Или какое-то другое ограничение?

Comment: А причем здесь Excel? Это код сервера. Он генерирует и отсылает файл. А уже потом вы открываете его в какой либо программе. Тут три слоя. Либо с сервера приходят не все данные, либо в файл не все сохраняется, либо Excel не может открыть много данных. Сначала определите точно в каком слое проблема.

Comment: Вот я ж и хочу узнать в каком слое проблема

Comment: Это необходимо сделать вам. `Content-Disposition: attachment` должен предложить сохранить файл. После сохранения проверьте размер. А на сервере в цикле вы можете его подсчитать `$size += length($row);` и записать например в лог. К тому же PHP в заголовки добавит `Content-Size`. Все эти три размера должны быть одинаковыми. Только после этого стоит разбираться с Excel (там есть ограничения на кол-во строк в xls, и в не сжатых форматах). Можно открыть с помощью Google Sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема разрешилась увеличением параметра `memory_limit` в `php.ini`. Сам движок использовал всю доступную память сервера.